# Issue with Sign In As Different User in Claim Based SharePoint 2010 Site with ADFS 2.0

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, adfs2.0

We have a SharePoint 2010 Web Site with Claim based Authentication configured with ADFS 2.0.

We have customized the SignOut option in Welcome.acx to point SignOut link to ADFS SignOut URL
i.e. `https://myadfsserver/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0`  which takes care of signing out user from all relying parties. But, if for some reason complete sign out was not done, and user tries to browse the site he does not have access to in that case user is redirected to SharePoint's OOB AccessDenind.aspx page.

This page provides a link to user to sign in as different user, but for some reason clicking on this link does not take user to ADFS sign in page, instead it takes user back to same AccessDenied Page only. Can somebody tell me how do I get this sign in as different user functionality working ?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint creates a cookie that is stored on the local disk and you have to force it to use a session based cookie.

http://www.shailensukul.com/2010/05/adfs-2-sharepoint-2010-signout.html